# Google Chrome Sync between work and home

Tags: google-chrome, sync

just saw something posted somewhere else regarding Google Chrome syncing between work at home.  I just got fired at work for my "internet use" because they are claiming they were able to print a 90 page report for just 8 days of working time there.  This seemed insane to me and i started thinking more and more about it.  I used google chrome on my phone, my home computer and my work computer....could they be tracking my personal use as well?

Comment: If they are claiming they were able to, let them give you the report for your alledged internet usage, so you can investigate yourself.

Comment: I think it's possible that they pulled the history file from Chrome's profile folder.

Comment: Doesn't sound realistic to me. People don't get fired without a warning and a decent explanation. There must be more detail to this.

Answer (score 0):

If you sync your Google chrome with the same user profile between multiple devices/computers and sync each of them together, your entire viewing history will be available to all of the devices, so it's entirely possible that they are passing off your own personal use as "work" use.
I suggest you obtain a copy of the data they found, and compare it to your own usage data over all machines, imagine if these 90 pages happened because your work computer all of a sudden synced days and days of personal usage data in just a few minutes?